# Python make plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have this code of a mortgage calculator. I would like to make this code into a plot using Matplotlib. The values I want is "Principal Paid" and "Interest Paid" as a line, showing the dollars on x and the years/dates on the y. I'm not sure how to start since I have input values, can someone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy_financial as npf
from datetime import date

def fixed_rate_mortgage(interest: float, years: int, payments_year: int, mortgage: int, start_date: str):
 
rng = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=years * payments_year, freq='MS')
rng.name = "Payment Date"
df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng, columns=['Payment', 'Principal Paid', 'Interest Paid', 'Ending Balance'], dtype='float')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.index += 1
df.index.name = "Period"

df["Payment"] = -1 * npf.pmt(interest/12, years*payments_year,mortgage)
df["Interest Paid"] = -1 * npf.ipmt(interest/payments_year, df.index, years*payments_year,mortgage)
df["Principal Paid"] = -1 * npf.ppmt(interest/payments_year, df.index, years*payments_year,mortgage)
df["Ending Balance"] = 0
df.loc[1, "Ending Balance"] = mortgage - df.loc[1, "Principal Paid"]
df = df.round(2)
df['Ending Balance'] = mortgage - df['Principal Paid'].cumsum()
df[df['Ending Balance'] < 0] = 0  
return df

payments_year = 12

years = input("Write how many years \n")
years = float(years)

interest = input("Write the interest \n")
interest = float(interest)

loan = input("Write the amount you want to loan \n")
loan = float(loan)

start_date = input("What is the starte date, put it in YYYY-MM-DD format")
year, month, day = map(int, start_date.split("-"))
start_date = date(year, month, day)

fixed_rate_mortgage(interest, years, payments_year, loan, start_date)
```

Comment: What are typical input values?  I'm getting ridiculous values of "Principal Paid" for my inputs of 10, 0.1, 10000, 2020-01-01

Comment: My code is original in another language, so I just quickly edited to english. That must be why

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `df` returned by `fixed_rate_mortgage` function is correct, the following code can be used as a starting point to plot the data frame using matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = df['Principal Paid']
x2 = df['Interest Paid']
y = df['Payment Date']

plt.plot(x1,y,label="Principal Paid")
plt.plot(x2,y,label="Interest Paid")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can further customise the plot by referring to matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/contents.html).